# Ruby on Rails: populate fake data extremely quick

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I can imagine it can be very easy just for lazy people like me to populate any fake data to db just with one rake (terminal) command.

I know about Faker, Populator and others but all of them, as far as i can see, need to write some (primitive but) code to make data more human friendly (defining type of random data directly and manually: emalis, names, prices and so on).

It makes sense in most cases but now in my case it would be enough for me to fill mysql varchar fields with any strings, text fields with any long text, int - with numbers and so on

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some example code that shows how to do that:

```
SKIP_COLUMNS = %w(id created_at updated_at)
RECORDS_COUNT = 10

# random data to fill
int = rand(1..100)
varchar = 'lorem'
text = 'big lorem'

# get models
@models = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.collect {|t| t.underscore.singularize.camelize }
@models.select {|m| m.constantize rescue @models.delete(m) }

# fill in data
@models.map(&:constantize).each do |model|
  model.columns_hash.each do |column|
    next if SKIP_COLUMNS.include?(column.first)

    # column_name = column.first
    # column_type = column.last.type

    RECORDS_COUNT.times do
      record = model.new

      case column.last.type
      when :integer
        record.send("#{column.first}=", int) 
      when :string
        record.send("#{column.first}=", varchar) 
      when :text
        record.send("#{column.first}=", text) 
      end

      record.save!
    end
  end
end
```

You can put that to rake task.

Comment: =) just exactly what i am doing right now while hopefully waiting for more elegant solution =)... i will accept it if nothing more interesting will be posted. and i am using Faker for generating int, varchar and text data and even more - i am trying to add some magic to fill fields with most appropriate data, generated with Faker based on field name and Faker method name similarity

Answer (score 1):

If speed is your aim, you should do two things:

- Use an in-memory database for your tests until you get to acceptance testing. In other words, consider something like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) for your integration tests (Some might say unit tests) rather than MySQL.
- Use [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to generate your fake data. Apparently, the data created by tools like that makes more sense than you prefer, but it is weird to me that you care about that. Regardless, it is a lot faster to use existing tools than to write code that generates gibberish just because you don't want data that look "too good."

Comment: it is ok to have good looking data =) but in my current case i have a table with more than 50 fields and for every of them i have to make a row like `Faker::Name.name => "Boring Letters"` when it is acceptable to have something like `dsdssdfwefwerw` and nothing more that can be done (i hope) with just one command (if necessary library with appropriate method exists)...

Comment: OK, so you meant reducing labor rather than increasing speed. Are all those fields required?

Comment: to be more clear: i need fake data in mysql db to test exporting to excel. and i need all columns in exported excel file. but content of this columns can be totally random (for now)